# How to make multiple sequential web requests that has dependencies to each other in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a reactive stream that calls to multiple other REST APIs and then process data and returns a List of Mono as below:

```
public Mono<List<ParcelInfo>> parcelEventsForReference(String parcelId, Postcode postcode) {
    return connector1.getParcelReference(parcelId) // 1. Mono<ResolvedParcelIds> (Web request 1)
        .flatMapIterable(ResolvedParcelIds::getParcelIds) // 2. Flux<ResolvedParcelId>
        .flatMap(id -> parcelEventsFor(id) // 3. Mono<ParcelInfo> 
            .map(parcel -> redactIfNecessary(parcel, id, postcode))) // 4. Flux<ParcelInfo>
        .collectList() // 5. Mono<List<ParcelInfo>>
                    .flatMapIterable(list -> list) // 6. Flux<ParcelInfo>
        .flatMap(this::getTrackingEvents)
        .collectList()
        .doOnError(throwable -> log.error(EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR, throwable.getMessage()));
 }

private Mono<ParcelInfo> parcelEventsFor(ResolvedParcelId id) {
    return connector2.getParcelBy(id).zipWith(connector3.getAdditionalInstructions(uid)) // (Web request 2,3)
            .map(tuple -> combineParcelEvents(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2()));
 }

private Mono<ParcelInfo> getTrackingEvents(ParcelInfo parcel) {
    TrackingRequest request = mapToRequest(parcel);
    return connector4.getTrackingForParcel(request) // (Web request 4)
        .map(trackingResponse -> addTracking(parcel, trackingResponse));
}

private ParcelInfo addTracking(ParcelInfo parcel, TrackingResponse trackingResponse) {
    parcelProgress.setTracking(trackingResponse);
    return parcel;
 }

public class ParcelInfo { 
    private List<ParcelBase> parcel;
    private TrackingResponse trackingResponse;
    private String additionalInstructions;
}

public class ResolvedParcelIds {
    private List<ResolvedParcelId> parcelIds;
}
```

My requirement is to execute the 4th web request using the 1,2,3 web request's processed response.
In this implementation I am able to get the desired output for success scenarion (if 1,2,3 requests return expected response), but I'm not sure whether this is the optimum solution.

My doubts are :

1. Should I use `zipWhen` operator to make sure 4th request only happens after 1,2,3 happens, if so how?
2. How to stop 4th request being executed if 1,2,3 requests are not success with http 200? (in connector level I have handled the error scenarios using `doOnError`)

Comment: I feel like someone didn't think this through properly. Every request has a response. Ofc, there are async methodologies, so you can create a response with an 'Accept' status immediately after every request. So, I wouldn't use a pending element in the code like zip. I would save the 1-2-3 requests into the cache. When you get the 4th request, you will have to handle cached data, and you can make a response with 200. Ofc, you should be prepared for what happens if there is no 2nd, 3rd or 4th request. So need a timeout on cached data.

Comment: Actually this was a feature there was already. My intention is just to integrate the 4th request based on earlier response. (new code is from `.flatMapIterable(list -> list) // 6. Flux<ParcelInfo>` in the stream). Is there a workaround without introducing a cache?

Comment: `flatMap` is a way to go in such scenarios. In general flow looks good but I would review error handling or adding retries at some points. No special handling needed at 4th step. Currently any error at any step (1,2,3,4) would cancel the flow and return error signal downstream.

Comment: @Alex thanks for the response. I was under the impression that i might need to use `zipWhen` operator. And im interested to know whether there is any possibility of blocking the stream with this current implementation?

Comment: not sure why you would need `zipWhen` here. If you need sequential processing and use results of the previous step `flatMap` is a good way in most cases. Assuming all async calls (`connector4.getTrackingForParcel`, `connector2.getParcelBy`, ..) are non-blocking - you should be good